# MAX DateTime value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In .NET, there's `var myMaxDate = DateTime.MaxValue;` which assigns the value of `12/31/9999 23:59:59`.

I need to send this value to my ASP.NET Core API. I tried producing this value in JavaScript using the following code but this doesn't seem to produce a valid date/time value.

```
var myRequest = {
   id: 123,
   name: "Some name",
   date: new Date("9999", "12", "31", 23, 59, 59).toISOString()
};
```

How do I produce this value in ISO string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to get the JS Date object:

```
new Date("9999-12-31T23:59:59")
```

however if you just call `.toISOString()`  it's a bit useless. Just do this:

```
date: "9999-12-31T23:59:59.000Z",
```

However your error was that the `monthIndex` (second parameter to the `Date()` constructor) is `0`-`11` not `1`-`12`. So for december you choose `11`:

```
new Date("9999", "11", "31", 23, 59, 59).toISOString()
```

However this is one of the reasons I would always provide a ISO8601 String when possible instead of magic numbers to the `Date()` constructor. ISO8601 is a universal standard over all languages.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out two important points i.e. the zero-based-month-values in JavaScript and using ISO8601 values. Thanks!

Comment: @Sam The 'zero-based-month-index' is well documented on any sane reference to the date function.  Not to be a smart ass, but you will save yourself LOTS of grief if you read the language and API documentation.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date